# Issue with Google code scanner: Failed to scan code

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, barcode-scanner, google-code

I am encountering an issue with the Google code scanner implementation in my Android app. The scanner works well on most devices, but on some, it fails with the error message "Failed to scan code." Upon further investigation, I found that the error code from the MlKitException is 13 (INTERNAL).

I have tried troubleshooting this issue, including manually downloading this [ModuleInstallClient](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/module-install-apis), updating dependencies, deleting Google Play services, and testing on different devices, but the problem persists only on specific devices.

Could someone please provide insights or solutions on how to resolve this issue? Alternatively, if there are any recommended alternative libraries for barcode scanning that could potentially address this issue, I would appreciate suggestions.